# How do I assign a pointer to a variable?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose we have a variable `k` which is equal 7:

```
int k=7;
int t=&k;
```

But this does not work. What's the mistake?

Comment: What does it mean when you say "it does not work"? Your compiler must have given you an error message. What was it? And what was unclear about that message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&k` takes the address of `k`. You probably mean

```
int *t = &k;
```

I have a good read for you: [Alf P. Steinbach's pointer tutorial](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B2oiI2reHOh4M2MzNzYwYzQtMGZkNC00NTljLWJiM2UtOGI0MmRkMTMyZGY4).

Answer (score 7):

You probably meant:

```
int k=7;
int *t=&k;
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare t as of type `int` and try to assign a value of type `int*`. `int*` cannot implicitely cast to type `int` which leads to the error you are observing. The solution is simple: declar t as `int*`. However, it seems you have no deeper understanding of pointers so you should fix that first before trying anything else.